# Start Bass with UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, bass

I found an example of UWP visualizer in [this link](https://github.com/wangfu91/Visualizer) but after I choose the audio file from the FilePicker and the Bass should start it returns an error: Attempt to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B), when Bass should start.

```
public async Task Play()
{
    if (CurrentPlayingFile == null) return;

    //CurrentPlayingFile = selectedFile;
    var filePath = CurrentPlayingFile.Path;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Bass.Start(); // Returns the error

        Bass.Init();

        _handle = Bass.CreateStream(filePath, 0, 0, BassFlags.AutoFree | BassFlags.Float);

        var length = Bass.ChannelBytes2Seconds(_handle, Bass.ChannelGetLength(_handle));

        Bass.ChannelPlay(_handle);
        IsPlaying = true;
    });
}
```

I created the folders: Visualizer-master\Visualizer.UI\Assets\lib\x64 and Visualizer-master\Visualizer.UI\Assets\lib\x86, with bass.dll and bass_fx.dll inside (because they didn't exist)

How can I start this by fixing the error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it is because the dll files are compiled for the ARM architecture? Try to run the app on something like a Raspberry Pi or whatever has an ARM processor.

Comment: Thanks Daniel... Is it possible to find dll for x64?

Comment: I don't know if that's the right thing but it looks like you could find it here http://www.un4seen.com/